# Why does Chocolatey not install on this Vagrant box?

Tags: powershell, vagrant, command-prompt, vagrantfile, chocolatey

I've installed chocolatey on my host machine (windows) using the powershell provision:

```
 Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

This is all fine and choco works on the host machine, but when I try to install it via `vagrant ssh`in the VM, it doesn't work at all. 
I've tried using scripts and adding them into the vagrantfile but with no luck.

**How can I get chocolatey on my windows vagrant VM?**

**My vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "kensykora/windows_2012_r2_standard"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2200

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end
  # chocolatey:
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "InstallChocolatey.ps1"
  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   sudo apt-get update
  #   sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "C:\Users\WorkExperience\Desktop\Working on Vagrant\WindowsServer2012-vagrant\shell\main.cmd"
  end
end
```

**installchocolatey.ps1 file:**

```
 $ChocoInstallPath = "$env:SystemDrive\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin"

  if (!(Test-Path $ChocoInstallPath)) {
      iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Try booting with the GUI on (either set the flag in the `Vagrantfile` or through your provider - eg. VirtualBox) and installing it manually there - it may help you find an error or other issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually have a duplicate configure block inside the main configure block, surrounding the provision method? If so, I suspect that this is valid Ruby code, but Vagrant is effectively not configured properly.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "C:\Users\WorkExperience\Desktop\Working on Vagrant\WindowsServer2012-vagrant\shell\main.cmd"
end
```

I would remove that extra configure block and leave only this

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "C:\Users\WorkExperience\Desktop\Working on Vagrant\WindowsServer2012-vagrant\shell\main.cmd"
```

Do you have a debug/verbose log output from `vagrant up`?

Also, you may find it helpful in versions 1.8.x+ of Vagrant to set `:powershell_elevated_interactive => true` as one of the options for `config.vm.provision :shell`. Not sure if this will make a difference with `.cmd` and `.bat` files, but for PowerShell it ensures it is still interactive with the desktop, which resolves some issues that can occur related to installers needing to be running interactively (even when they are unattended/silent).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I managed to do it by adding the script to install chocolatey directly into the jason! I also did what you said, which I think helped me a lot! Thanks Anthony