# Vagrant ssh into a Windows 10 guest: PATH does not include tools provisioned with Chocolatey

Tags: windows, path, vagrant

We are running a Windows 10 Vagrant box, for which we made the base box with Packer.
The host is macOS 10.14.5

During Vagrant provisioning, we user Chocolatey to install different build tools we need.
Yet, if we `vagrant ssh` into the running box, we don't have access to these tools. Inspecting the `PATH`, it appears that it does not contain the directory for said tools.

Yet, if we run the box with its UI, and we log-in in the VM UI and launch "cmd.exe" from the start menu, then the `PATH` contains all the entries installed by Chocolatey.

What do we have to do to ensure the `PATH` is correct for `vagrant ssh`?

---

EDIT: Running `vagrant winrm -c "echo \$env:PATH"` does display the correct `PATH`

Comment: which SSH client gets opened the one supplied with vagrant or something else? A screenshot would be good

Comment: @TarunLalwani How to check which ssh client was opened by the `vagrant ssh` command? A screenshot of which screen are you interested into?

Comment: After you execute the SSH what opens up? Can you show how the SSH client looks like

Comment: @TarunLalwani I see what might be the misunderstanding: the host is a macOS system, and every command is executed in `bash`. So nothing opens up, just bash ssh client showing up in the current terminal.

Comment: Try running the `env` command after ssh and add the output of the same to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am not following you, `env` is not a Windows command, so I cannot run it after ssh'ing into the Windows box.

Comment: You can run `gci env:` to get a similar effect to the Linux `env` command. I've found the the elevated argument mentioned in this other SO answer was required for `choco` to be found without requiring using the `vagrant-reload` plugin or restarting the VM myself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600147/3794873